# On the continuity of the normal component of the diffusion flux

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vector-fields, mathematics, continuum-mechanics, diffusion

Is the normal component of diffusion flux is always continuous? I know the continuity at any surface would mean the amount of fluid that is entering through the surface is the same amount that is going out. If the normal component of the diffusion flux is discontinuous, what would be a physical interpretation of that?

Comment: Since a surface has no ability to accumulate material, in must always equal out.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.